# error regarding terminal in shopify hydrogen ;

Tags: visual-studio-code, shopify, shopify-hydrogen

PS C:\Users\verma\Document02\shopify-hydrogen\hydra> npm run dev

> hydra@1.0.6 dev
> shopify hydrogen dev --codegen

Environment variables injected into MiniOxygen:

SESSION_SECRET        from local .env
PUBLIC_STORE_DOMAIN   from local .env

╭─ success ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                                                       │
│  Initial build: 3120ms                                                                │
│  MiniOxygen (Worker Runtime) development server running.                              │
│                                                                                       │
│  View Hydrogen app: http://localhost:3000                                             │
│  View GraphiQL API browser: http://localhost:3000/graphiql                            │
│  View server network requests: http://localhost:3000/subrequest-profiler              │
│                                                                                       │
╰───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯

Error: Failed to fetch changelog
at getChangelog (file:///C:/Users/verma/Document02/shopify-hydrogen/hydra/node_modules/@shopify/cli-hydrogen/dist/commands/hydrogen/upgrade.js:175:9)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async displayDevUpgradeNotice (file:///C:/Users/verma/Document02/shopify-hydrogen/hydra/node_modules/@shopify/cli-hydrogen/dist/commands/hydrogen/upgrade.js:661:21) ;

//////////////////////////////

when i do npm run dev i get this error how to resolve this

i also re-install node - module but the error is not resolve guide me.